# Laravel app in sub domain

Tags: laravel

I want to know is that possible to have one laravel app installed but works differently in 2 directories or no?

## purpose

i want have my blogging application in `domain.com` and my store application in `store.domain.com` 
basically is one  laravel application and different installed packages for each directory but  authentication and roles are the same.

Comment: yeah sure.. you need to manage your routing with subdomain and without subdomain..

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is posible.  You can use apache or nginx

Answer (score 0):

point your sub domain to your laravel public folder (e.g: `store.domain.com` => `/public_html/public`). also you can enable wildcard dns that not recommended.

create a route for your [sub domain](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-group-sub-domain-routing):

```
Route::domain('{store}.domain.com')->group(function () {
    Route::get('user/{id}', function ($store, $id) {
        //
    });
});
```

Comment: in this case what will be in my subdomain folder? i means all my views, assets are in `public_html` then what i put in `store` folder?

Comment: your sub domain point to Laravel `public` directory. in cpanel, create a sub domain and select laravel public folder instead of default sub domain directory. Actually when you create a sub domain, it will create a directory with sub domain name. so you must point your sub domain to the laravel public folder. 

for example: your project path is: `/domain/domain.com/public_html/public`, url is: `www.domain.com/public`
your sub domain must pont to `/domain/domain.com/public_html/public` instead of `/domain/domain.com/public_html/store`